# p:column header facet is not shown when rendered attribute is used on p:column

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `<p:dataTable>`. I would like to render a `<p:column>` conditionally as follows:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{abcList}" var="abc">
  <p:column rendered="#{headerShow}">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="header" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{abc.hijk}" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

When `#{headerShow}` is `false`, then the column is hidden.
When `#{headerShow}` is `true`, then the column is shown, but without header.
When I hardcode `rendered="true"`, then the column is shown with header.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: does `<p:column rendered="#{headerShow}" headerText="someText">` works for you when you remove the `<f:facet name="header">`?

Comment: Yes,if `<f:facet name="header">` remove then it can work.

Comment: Please show an SSCCE instead of an obfuscated snippet. What condition exactly do you *really* have in `#{headerShow}`? Is it depending on `#{abc}` or so?

Answer (score 1):

`<f:facet name="header">` is outdated for column names. Primefaces 3.0 introduced the headerText attribute doing exactly the same.

So try this instead:

```
<p:column rendered="#{headerShow}" headerText="header">
  <h:outputText value="#{abc.hijk}" />
</p:column>
```